# Is there an equivalent for the SAS "intnx" command in python?

Tags: python, sas

I am a beginner in python and stuck on translating a piece of code from SAS to Python (see below). How would I recreate the "intnx"-command in line 10 in Python, which introduces a 3-month-lag to the actual date (datadate) in order to create the variable "HouDate".

```
data data._1_compustat_prep (keep = gvkey tic datadate fyear HouDate HouYear ib at dvc act che 
lct dlc txp dp ibc oancf);
retain gvkey tic datadate fyear HouDate HouYear;
set data._0_compustat_students;

  if indfmt   = 'INDL' and datafmt = 'STD';

  format HouDate DDMMYY10.;
  format DataDate DDMMYY10.;
  HouDate = intnx("month", datadate, +3, "E");
  if month(HouDate) >= 7 then HouYear = year(HouDate) + 1; else HouYear = year(HouDate);

  if mdy(07,01,1963) <= HouDate <= mdy(06,30,2009);
  if exchg in (11,12,14,15,17);
  if 6000 <= sich <= 6999 then delete;

run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and [`dateutil`] libraries to help you with this. In particular the [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) and <s>[`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)</s> [`dateutil.realtivedelta.relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) classes.
*The `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta` class is better than the `datetime.timedelta` here, because the latter won't allow you to specify a delta with units bigger than days, when the former does.*

Additionally, I've added type hints in the code, to make it easier to understand. I corresponds to the syntax `xx:yy` where `xx` is the variable name, and `yy` its type.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

lag:relativedelta = relativedelta(months=3)
datadate:datetime = datetime(year=2022, month=8, day=25, hour=11, minute=37, second=8)
HouDate:datetime = datadate + lag

HouYear:int = HouDate.year
if HouDate.month >= 7:
    HouYear += 1

print("{} || {}".format(HouYear, HouDate))
```

> 2023 || 2022-11-25 11:37:08

---

As the author mentioned in one of their comment:

> how would you do the commands above for whole columns in a dataframe?

Here is the way I'd do it when using a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

lag:relativedelta = relativedelta(months=3)

df:pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({
    "datadate": [
        datetime(year=2022, month=1, day=1, hour=1, minute=1, second=1),
        datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=2, hour=2, minute=2, second=2),
        datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=3, hour=3, minute=3, second=3)
    ]
})

df["HouDate"] = df.datadate.apply(lambda x: x+lag)
df["HouYear"] = df.HouDate.apply(lambda x: x.year if x.month < 7 else x.year+1)

print(df)
```

Pre-treatment dataframe:

|  | datadate |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 01:01:01 |
| 1 | 2022-06-02 02:02:02 |
| 2 | 2022-10-03 03:03:03 |

Post-treatment dataframe:

|  | datadate | HouDate | HouYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 01:01:01 | 2022-04-01 01:01:01 | 2022 |
| 1 | 2022-06-02 02:02:02 | 2022-09-02 02:02:02 | 2023 |
| 2 | 2022-10-03 03:03:03 | 2023-01-03 03:03:03 | 2023 |

Comment: Thx a lot! Any idea how to recreate "if month(HouDate) >= 7 then HouYear = year(HouDate) + 1; else HouYear = year(HouDate);" Statement in line 10?

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate that

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yet, I am still struggling to execute the commands on a whole column, i.e. 'HouDate' contains the lagged dates of 'datadate', and now I want the column 'HouYear' to contain the year of 'HouDate' (+1), but only if the month of 'HouDate' is greater than 7. So how would you do the commands above for whole columns in a dataframe?

Comment: Please note that you never mentioned you were working on Dataframes, which is why this answer isn't satisfactory to you. I will try to find a solution though.

Comment: If the answer is now covering your issue, please remember to mark it as solved